# I have a laravel project with 2 tables (users and roles). In a roles view, I am trying to display a count of users who are using that specific role

Tags: laravel

My tables areas follows

roles table (id, roleName, roleDesc)

users table (id, name, role, email)

When adding a new user, I insert a role eg "Admin" into the role column of the user.

My problem is that I want to show the number of users who have that role in a view data table that displays list of roles. Eg would simply be an integer of number of members who share that role, eg 5.

In my roleController, I am fetching records using

```
$roles = Role::all();
$users = User::all();
```

I have managed to display a count of users with role "Admin", but this ofcourse just duplicated all down the datatable with eg "1"

```
$RoleCount = User::where('role', '=', 'Admin')->count();
```

So, I think I need to use a join or something to replace the 'Admin' above, with current roleName.

I hope that makes sense and I hope someone can help me find a solution. I know this is pretty elementary, but trying to rap my head around joins and having a bit of trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it will be great to use Relationships ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships))
With relationships it will be super easy.

1. Change Users table, so you have there NO the name of role, but ID of role = columns id, name, role_id, email
2. In Role model add relationship to User, and in User model add relationship to Role:

Model User.php - add method

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role'); //use your correct namespace
}
```

Model Role.php - add method

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User'); //use your correct namespace
}
```

And then just select all roles with count of users:

```
$roles = Role::withCount('users')->get();
```

In your view:

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
    {{ $role->roleName }} - {{ $role->users_count }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Legend, let me give this a try, makes sense, thanks  Autista_z.

Comment: Hi Autista_z., I gave it a try, looks promising. I put the relationships into the models and replaced my DB query in the rolesController with your query to select all roles with count of users. I also integrated your foreach into my view. Unfortunately I get an error "Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on null" if I replace your lookup with my select all lookup from before, I get no error, but the count isn't showing in the view. Sorry, I'm new to relationships, thankyou for showing them to me. They will be extremely useful. Would you know where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: This looks like relationship is not working properly. Do you named column for role in users table role_id? If no, you can specify in relationship name of foreign key column: `$this->hasMany('App\User', 'name_of_column_in_users_table_for_role', 'name_of_primary_key_in_roles_table');`

Comment: Thankyou so much Autista_z, it now works, wow, soooo happy. You have taught me a new tool to use that I will use all the time, thankyou. In the end, I just needed to specify tables per your above and also return it. This is my query " return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'role', 'id');", it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Autista_z or anyone, I am just trying to really understand this. Now that I have the realtionships, I have a view that shows a list of users and their role. 1 User can have one role, but a role can have many users.  I am trying to show the roleName in the users datatable, instead of the role id.  I've had a good look at the Laravel docs, but struggling to convert the role ID in the user table to a roleName.

Comment: `$users = User::with('role')->get();` and then in Loop for users `@foreach($users as $user) {{ $user->role->roleName }}`

Comment: Thanks again Autista_z, I was on the right track, but I didn't have $user->role->roleName,. I think I'm starting to understand relationships in Laravel. Thankyou for your excellent help.

Comment: I now get error "Trying to get property 'roleName' of non-object" when trying to view the user table. When I do a dd($users) in the userController, in the dump when I expand relations, I see role=>null, so leads me to believe something wrong again with the relationship or the search is not yielding a result.

Comment: I think it will be incorrect relationship  setting in Users.php model.

Comment: Thanks Autista_z, I will have a look at it again, I think you are right. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: FInally figured it out. I missed at the very top when you wrote " columns id, name, role_id, email" I missed the role_id. I now understand Laravel basically expects this and with this colum, it effectively made it all work. So, my making that change to user table and doing a fresh migration, was able to use your code above that worked flawlessly. Thankyou Autista_z